# Comment dire « Red Herring » ?

Tags: traduction, expressions, anglais

Comment pourrait-on traduire **red herring** dans le sens d'un argument qui est gênant ou qui mène ailleurs dans une discussion?

Dans le sens où le dire mène distrait de la discussion et piège les arguments.

Pour voir la définition en anglais: [**red herring**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/red%20herring)

Ce que je voudrais c'est une expression **équivalente**!! (dans la mesure du possible évidemment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Chiffon rouge**,

*Agiter le chiffon rouge* pour faire craindre un danger ou attirer l'attention s'emploie aussi dans le monde de la *[phynance](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/phynance)*...
... c'est aussi une relation animale suggérée : le taureau se laisse divertir par la muleta, le hareng nous égare par sa couleur.

Synonymes :

> - échappatoire,
> - faux-fuyant,
> - dérobade,
> - excuse,
> - fuite,
> - prétexte,
> - subterfuge.

Ou encore :

> - Manœuvre de diversion
> - Détournement d'attention

Comment: +1 pour *manoeuvre de diversion* qui est probablement la meilleure traduction, même si on perd l'image.

Answer (score 3):

Dans les discussions passionnées, il est commun d'entendre

> Ne change pas de sujet !

Il s'agit d'indiquer à son interlocuteur qu'on a vu qu'il changeait volontairement le sujet de la discussion car il n'était pas à son avantage.

---

On emploie plus familièrement l'expression *"**noyer le poisson**"*.

Comment: +1 pour *noyer le poisson* qui n'est pas un équivalent exact mais suffisamment proche, avec le bénéfice de faire référence au même champ lexical. Bien trouvé.

Answer (score 0):

L’idée de ‘a red herring’ ressemble à “un [faux-fuyant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/faux-fuyant),” d’après mon interprétation de ‘CNRTL’:

> B.− Au fig. Moyen détourné par lequel on se tire d'une situation
>   embarrassante, on évite de s'engager. Synon. échappatoire, excuse,
>   prétexte

et d’après mon interprétation de ces résultats ici chez ‘[Reverso-contexte](http://context2.reverso.net/info.php?langFrom=fr&langTo=en&q=faux-fuyant&langTot=fr-en).’